# 4th parameter of subscribe RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp

```
compositeDisposable.add(
            myUseCase
                .getData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    {
                        println(it)
                    },
                    {
                        println(it)
                    },
                    {
                        println("test")
                    },
                    {
                        println("whatIsIt?" + it) <- I get this all the time ...
                    }
                )
        )
```

I'm newbie when it comes to RxJava2.
My API works (I checked it using Postman and I got a list with items) but using rxjava2 with retrofit it all time go to last `println` and `it` shows = `"0"`
What could be wrong ?

After that I get no response and no errors.
Just in logcat "END GET" from okhttp log.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for rxJava are at https://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/

According to them, the 4th parameter is onSubscribe-  a function called when the observable is subscriber to (when you'll start to get notifications).  The parameter to it is the disposable representing the subscription.

Comment: after that I get in logcat "END GET" from httpok log, without items and without errors

Comment: I have no idea what that is because I don't have enough of your code to know what you're actually doing.  There's nothing in the code posting having anything to do with http.